# Bring window to focus with python periodically

Tags: python, win32gui

```
import win32gui
import time

def windowEnumerationHandler(hwnd, top_windows):
    top_windows.append((hwnd, win32gui.GetWindowText(hwnd)))
if __name__ == "__main__":
    top_windows = []
    win32gui.EnumWindows(windowEnumerationHandler, top_windows)
    for i in top_windows:
        print(i)
        if "zoom" in i[1].lower():
            print(i, 'is found')
            while True:
                win32gui.ShowWindow(i[0],5)
                win32gui.SetForegroundWindow(i[0])
                time.sleep(1)
```

I've heard that zoom monitors whether the window is not in focus for more than 30 seconds, so I've been working on a way to repetitively throw it to the front while I work on other projects. The problem is the code raises an exception

```
0, 'SetForegroundWindow', 'No error message is available'
```

and the window just flashes yellow. Same problem with chrome as well. Would appreciate some help here :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem while I was trying to `SetForegroundWindow(hwnd)`. The icon on the taskbar was just flashing, but the program stayed in the background. As you can read here: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setforegroundwindow?redirectedfrom=MSDN

"An application cannot force a window to the foreground while the user is working with another window. Instead, Windows flashes the taskbar button of the window to notify the user."

For me helped:

```
import win32gui, win32com.client     


    shell = win32com.client.Dispatch("WScript.Shell")
    shell.SendKeys('%')
    win32gui.SetForegroundWindow(hwnd)
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a very old post but ...
If `win32gui.SetForegroundWindow(hwnd)` doesn't work or flashes the app on the taskbar you can use this ...

```py
if win32gui.GetForegroundWindow() != hwnd:
    win32gui.ShowWindow(hwnd, win32con.SW_MINIMIZE)
    win32gui.ShowWindow(hwnd, win32con.SW_RESTORE)
```

You can also move the window to different desktops with pyvda ...

```py
from pyvda import VirtualDesktop, get_apps_by_z_order
from psutil import process_iter
from win32gui import GetWindowText, GetForegroundWindow, ShowWindow
from win32con import SW_MINIMIZE, SW_RESTORE
from os import startfile


process = [process for process in process_iter() if process.name() == 'firefox.exe']
if not bool(len(process)):
    startfile(r'C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe')
    while not bool(len(process)):
        process = [process for process in process_iter() if process.name() == 'firefox.exe']

window = [window for window in get_apps_by_z_order(current_desktop = False) if 'Mozilla Firefox' in GetWindowText(window.hwnd)][0]
if window.desktop.number != VirtualDesktop.current().number:
    window.move(VirtualDesktop.current())

if GetForegroundWindow() != window.hwnd:
    ShowWindow(window.hwnd, SW_MINIMIZE)
    ShowWindow(window.hwnd, SW_RESTORE)
```